# How to add a class to the parent element

Tags: jquery

I have `li` which contains `a`. When I click on `a` some action occurs and the active class is added.

I need that when clicking on `a`, the active class is added for `li`. Right now my code doesn't work and doesn't add any class. How can this be done?

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active { border: 1px solid rebeccapurple }
a.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a>Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: actually your code works removing the `active` class from any anchor in the document and adding it back to the currently clicked anchor and its `li` parent. The question are: why your anchor has no content? why didn't you use a parent `<ul>`/`<ol>` for your list items? why don't you have a style for the elements having the `active` class so you can see when it's being applied?

Comment: *doesn't add any class* - is that just because you're missing the styling for that class?  **edit** I've added css to your snippet so that you can see it working fine.  If it's not working your real-case, then please update the snippet to provide code that **demonstrates the problem**.  See [mcve].

Comment: *doesn't add any class* - as it's an `<a>`, does your code (not the snippet) have an `href=`?   could be that your page is navigating / reloading so that your class gets reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you code more or less works

Perhaps this is what you want

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $('a').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
a.active {
  background-color: yellow
}

li.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Click</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Click</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Click</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Click</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

NOTE that if the `a` navigates somewhere else that also has this navigation, it will not keep the class unless you use localStorage.

If you want to stop it from navigating you can add

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a working code, I did it and everything worked:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active {
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple
}

a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="active">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```